# Authorization in swagger is missing

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Please help me figure out what I am missing here. There is no authorize for me to add token.

```
const options = {
    swaggerDefinition: {
     swagger:"2.0",
     info:{
        title: "Franchising API",
        version: "1.0.0.0",
        description: "Franchising API Information"
      },    
      server: [" ${process.env.MONGO_HOST}:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}"],     
      schemes: ['http', 'https'],
      basePath :"/api/v1",
      securityDefinition : {
        APIKeyHeader:{
          type:"apiKey",
          name: "x-api-token",
          in : "header"
        },
        BasicAuth:{
          type:"basic"
        }
      }  
    },    
    apis: ['./api/v1/routes/franchise.js','./api/v1/routes/reason.js','./api/v1/routes/upload.js']
}
```

[image]

Please help me :D TIA

Comment: Try adding `security: [{APIKeyHeader: []}, {BasicAuth: []}]` before `securityDefinition`.

Comment: still the same sir